# MailChimp Form Action Hash

Tags: php, hash, mailchimp

What is the get variable "u" on the MailChimp signup form? If it's a hash of something does someone know how to generate it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a hash of anything, it is a unique id for your user account. Depending on what you're doing, [this](http://apidocs.mailchimp.com/how-to/forward-to-a-friend.php) may be helpful.